# What technology should I use/how should I deploy my killer web app?

Tags: deployment, scale

I finally decided it was time to write that "killer web app" we all dream about. :-)  I've been a programmer for almost as long as I can remember so I'm not scared of technology, but I haven't been active in the web world for about a decade.  Looking for some help on the direction I should go.

The app I'm considering: (in order of importance)

```
1) will need to charge my customers securely using someone else's service
2) must scale easily 
3) must be cheap to deploy 
4) must be reasonably responsive (much of it will be client side 
   javascript, but there is some server interaction) 
5) will need a database on the back end (not a huge database, but it will 
   need to scale with the customer base)
```

I'm thinking of using the following:

Technology: mySQL, PHP, Javascript
Deployment: Amazon Cloud
Payment: Paypal

Is this the right direction??  (Any tutorial links would be greatly appreciated)

Comment: it sounds ok but try with new things like nodeJS, jQuery etc. Also give a try at mongodb (some noSQL databases but I am not sure whether it supports transactions as SQL does). Good luck.!!!

Comment: I'm not sure you'll find many startups choosing PHP for new projects in 2010.  It's a capable language, but I'd encourage you to investigate a Python, .NET, or Java framework.

Comment: "I haven't been active in the web world for about a decade." Don't write that killer app now. Start with something you can use. Add a feature here and there. Keep building your skills and adding features. Perhaps then you'll have something worth sharing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use what you know best.

Don't worry too much about technology choices. The technologies you list are "safe" choices in the sense that many successful web apps have been built with them, so you know it can be done. I'd suggest sticking with mainstream technologies for that reason.

Also, don't worry too much about particular techniques and architectures. If your app really takes off, you're going to end up constantly redesigning the internal architecture anyway to keep up with traffic. Just keep it flexible.

Comment: Great advice. Most of my experience is in .Net (winforms). As much as I dislike ASP I could write an app fairly quickly. It looks like Amazon supports ASP in it's EC2 cloud which would make scaling it out easier. PHP would probably make for a more responsive and cheaper app eventually.  But, like you suggest right now I just need to test the business model. Thanks for the great advice.

Answer (score 0):

If you could use Java or Python instead of PHP, check out Google App Engine: http://code.google.com/appengine/

1. Use paypal or Chargify or amazon
2. Check
3. Check (free until a high limit)
4. Check (google servers)
5. As long as you don't *require* a relational database

Comment: Looks like they have a per user charge of $8 a month. Cool for a corporate app that's heavily used.  My app will charge $3 for users and almost all my users will be relitively casuaul one/two/three time users so probably won't work for me. :-(  Thanks for the info though.  Great idea.

Comment: Sorry, the link I sent you features "App Engine for Business," but the regular "App Engine" is much, much cheaper.  http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/billing.html

Comment: Thanks!!  That's much better for me! :-)